# PIC16F84A Switch Toggle

Tags: assembly, toggle, microcontroller, pic

Hello i'm trying to make a circuit where in my microcontroller i am trying to toggle an LED on or off by the push of a button. I am trying to toggle LED pin D2 with the button in RB0. This is my circuit

[image]

heres is my code:

```
    STATE EQU 0DH

    ;set up
    BSF STATUS, RP0 
    CLRF TRISA
    MOVLW 01H
    MOVWF TRISB
    MOVLW 01H
    MOVWF STATE ;state = 1
    MOVLW 0H
    BCF STATUS, RP0

    ;program start
    START MOVWF PORTA

    BTFSS PORTB, 0
    GOTO START
    GOTO TOGGLE

    TOGGLE DECFSZ STATE, 1
           GOTO OFF
           GOTO ON

    ON    MOVLW 2H
          MOVWF STATE ;state = 2
          MOVLW 1H
          GOTO START

    OFF   MOVLW 0H
          GOTO START
```

The problem is when i toggle the led on, it turns on all right but after a few seconds it turns off even though i didnt press the button im really out of ideas i need help . Also sometimes the button doesnt work and is very buggy im so confused

Comment: perhaps the 100 pull-down isn't always making sure the pin "sees" low. I prefer pull-up with 10k (the switch connects pin to gnd, with a 10k to +5V). just like  you do with -mclr, (but with a bigger resistor)

Comment: I tried and changed my code for the pull-up yet the results are the same :/

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea about pic asm. "toggle" is always a bit tricky, since you have to debounce the input and just use the triggers (and not toggle all the time as long as the button is pressed). Are you sure the button is the problem? Have you tried to make 2 LEDs, one "while the button is pressed" and one "the button is not pressed", to see it the "reading the button" works well?

Comment: Put in main loop instruction `clrwdt`, watchdog can reset the MCPU!

Comment: So i changed the 100 pulldown to 1000 ohms and added the clrwdt code and it works! No more turning off when its on! However the button is still buggy and sometimes it doesnt work or turns on then off. Perhaps this is because i didnt debounce the switch? if it is then its no problem, My main problem is solved :)

Comment: Debounce is absolutly necessary, a least a capacitor over your switch. A small delay in your mainloop could also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the circuit your are working with at present:

[PIC16F84A button input 2 LEDs for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4zZp.png)

This code should toggle LED D2 on a button press:

```
;   
; Project: 16F84A_button+LEDs_v2
; File: main.asm
; Target: PIC16F84A
; IDE: MPLAB v8.92
; Assembler: MPASM v5.51
; Assembler mode: Absolute
;   
; Additional files:
;   P16F84A.INC
;                           PIC16F84A
;                   +----------:_:----------+
;             <>  1 : RA2               RA1 : 18 <> LED_GREEN D1
;             <>  2 : RA3               RA0 : 17 <> LED_GREEN D2
;             <>  3 : RA4/T0CKI        OSC1 : 16 <- 4MHz crystal
;    ICSP_VPP ->  4 : MCLR             OSC2 : 15 -> 4MHz crystal
;         GND ->  5 : GND               VDD : 14 <- 5v0
;      BUTTON <>  6 : RB0/INT       PGD/RB7 : 13 <> ICSP_PGD
;             <>  7 : RB1           PGC/RB6 : 12 <> ICSP_PGC
;             <>  8 : RB2               RB5 : 11 <> 
;             <>  9 : RB3               RB4 : 10 <> 
;                   +-----------------------:
;                            DIP-18 
;
; Description:
;    Toggle LED pin D2 when the button on RB0 is pressed.
;   
#include "p16F84A.inc"
;
    list    r=dec, n=0, c=255   ; make default radix decimal, no page breaks and maximum line length in list file
    errorlevel -302             ; suppress register not in bank zero warning
;
; Setup the configuration word
;
     __CONFIG _FOSC_HS & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _CP_OFF
;
; Constants
;
#define DEBOUNCE_COUNT      H'FF'
#define BUTTON_RB0_MASK     B'00000001'
#define BUTTON_RB0_PRESSED  B'00000000'
#define BUTTON_RB0_RELEASED B'00000001'
#define LED_D2_MASK         B'00000001'
;
; Memory
;
  CBLOCK H'0D'
    DEBOUNCE_COUNTER
    BUTTON_SAMPLE
    BUTTON_CHANGED
    BUTTON_STABLE
  ENDC
;
; Code
;
    ;set up
    BANKSEL TRISA
    CLRF    TRISA               ; Make all of PORTA outputs
    MOVLW   H'01'
    MOVWF   TRISB               ; Make RB0 an input, RB1 to RB7 outputs
    BANKSEL PORTA
    CLRF    PORTA               ; Make all PORTA outputs zero

    ;setup button debouncer
    BANKSEL DEBOUNCE_COUNTER
    CLRF    BUTTON_SAMPLE
    CLRF    BUTTON_CHANGED
    CLRF    BUTTON_STABLE
    MOVLW   0

    ;program start
RESTART_DEBOUNCER:
    XORWF   BUTTON_SAMPLE,F     ; Update sample to current state
    MOVLW   DEBOUNCE_COUNT
    MOVWF   DEBOUNCE_COUNTER

START:
    MOVF    PORTB,W             ; Read current button state
    ANDLW   BUTTON_RB0_MASK     ; Make all non-button bits zero
    XORWF   BUTTON_SAMPLE,W     ; Compare against last sample
    BNZ     RESTART_DEBOUNCER   ; Branch is button is still changing
    MOVF    DEBOUNCE_COUNTER,F  ; Check button debounce counter for zero
    BZ      BUTTONS_DEBOUNCED   ; Branch when button has been stable long enough
    DECF    DEBOUNCE_COUNTER,F  ; Update debounce count
    GOTO    START               ; Loop scanning for button changes

BUTTONS_DEBOUNCED:
    MOVF    BUTTON_SAMPLE,W     ; Read new stable button state
    XORWF   BUTTON_STABLE,W     ; Compare against last stable button state
    MOVWF   BUTTON_CHANGED      ; Save Buttons that change since last stable button state
    BZ      START               ; Branch when no button changed state
    XORWF   BUTTON_STABLE,F     ; Update stable button state

    MOVF    BUTTON_CHANGED,W
    ANDLW   BUTTON_RB0_MASK
    BZ      START               ; Branch because RB0 did not change
    MOVF    BUTTON_STABLE,W
    ANDLW   BUTTON_RB0_MASK
    XORLW   BUTTON_RB0_PRESSED
    BZ      TOGGLE              ; Branch when RB0 changed to pressed
    GOTO    START

TOGGLE:
    MOVLW   LED_D2_MASK
    XORWF   PORTA,F
    GOTO    START

    END
```